# ignore nested results in preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I want to make a match on the first occurance of characters inside two curling brackets, but ignore the ones inside it.

```
{{some text here {{nested text here}} another text {{another nested text here}} final text}}
```

So the result must be

```
some text here {{nested text here}} another text {{another nested text here}} final text
```

but this search

```
preg_match_all("^\{{(.*?)\}}^", $string, $results);
```

gives me the ones inside the first pair of brackets:

```
$results[0][0] = nested text here
$results[0][1] = another nested text here
```

Is there any way to achieve this with preg_match_all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nested structures often cause problems with regular expressions (since they make the language to be matched more complex than regular). PCRE is one of the engines, that does allow matching of them, because it supports recursion. If you never have single curly brackets inside your double-brackets, you could use this pattern:

```
'/\{\{[^{}]*(?:(?R)[^{}]*)*\}\}/'
```

Where `(?R)` nests the whole pattern inside itself again.

I am not sure how well PCRE optimizes, but you can help a little, by making all repetitions [possessive](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html). That suppresses backtracking, which is not necessary here, since all consecutive repetitions are mutually exclusive:

```
'/\{\{[^{}]*+(?:(?R)[^{}]*+)*+ \}\}/'
```

If you do allow single brackets, you could do something similar with lookaheads, but this already shows why regular expressions aren't really made for nested structures (even if the engine supports it):

```
'/\{\{(?:(?!\{\{|\}\}).)*(?:(?R)(?:(?!\{\{|\}\}).)*)*\}\}/'
```

Now instead of non-`{}` characters, we allow the repetition of any character, unless it marks the beginning of a `{{` or `}}`. Again, making it possessive might be a good idea:

```
'/\{\{(?:(?!\{\{|\}\}).)*+(?:(?R)(?:(?!\{\{|\}\}).)*+)*+\}\}/'
```

Comment: great answer! thanks! It works for now. These regular expresions give me hard time understanding them, probably bacause they look so messy. I'll take some time to analize your answer, but the first one works (although it may not be the optimal one).

Comment: @flaviu the tutorial I linked for possessive quantifiers is a great resource in general. if you check out grouping and lookarounds there as well, it should help a lot. and here is [the documentation for recursive patterns](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php).